# MyPy needs type annotations for derived class variable

Tags: python, mypy

```py
from __future__ import annotations # Needed on old versions of Python

from typing import ClassVar

class Base:
  X: ClassVar[dict[str, int]] = {}

class Derived(Base):
  X = {}
```

Pyright is completely happy with this code, and correctly infers the type of `Derived.X` as `dict[str, int]`. But if you run it through MyPy 0.910 it gives this error for `Derived.X`:

```
example.py:9: error: Need type annotation for "X" (hint: "X: Dict[<type>, <type>] = ...")
```

Why? Is that a bug in MyPy? Is there any way around it (without just giving in and adding redundant type annotations everywhere)?

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue was [reported](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10375) as a bug in April 2021. There doesn't appear to be any discussion on the issue (as of December 2021) as to whether it *is* a bug or not.